# To IDE or Not? A beginner developer's dilemma

Tags: python, ide, anjuta

Basically, me and a friend of mine are just planning to work on a Python project which would have GUI interface, and enable file transfer over and remote file listing. We have most of the tools which we are going to use, Glade, Python etcetera.

I just want to know if I should use an IDE or not.

I've heard only good things about Anjuta, but not convinced of its Python support; care to comment?
And also is there any other good IDE I should check out?

Currently I am just planning on coding as usual in vim.

Comment: See also [IDE or Text Editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136056/ide-or-text-editor), [Why should I use an IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208193/why-should-i-use-an-ide). The question may not be entirely language agnostic, but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous IDEs you can check out. Take a look at [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk/), [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide), [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/).

I personally don't think IDEs add *that* much to software development (on this scale and in this language). Python has fine external debugging tools and refactoring is not that hard with a program of this size.

Do you currently use or want to use any features you miss in your current editor? If so, pick another one, else, stick with what you like most.

As long as it has version control integration you should be fine.

Comment: VCS integration is hardly a requirement. You can always use it from the command line just fine. Otherwise mostly agreed.

Answer (score 8):

The ability to debug using an IDE makes your life so much easier.

Comment: do you have a favorite Python3 IDE?

Answer (score 4):

Python is a particularly strange language in that having a full-fledged IDE doesn't really add much (and some would argue that an IDE tends to severely limit your thinking-flow in Python). I've been using regular Vim and Gedit to develop in Python and never really missed using IDE.

Text editors like Vim or Emacs itself can be configured quite flexibly to match an IDE power though, so it doesn't really matter which way you go.

Comment: +1 I normally use an IDE for programming but when I started with Python I've started with Vim an stuck to it, never really feeling a need for an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I do most my Python coding in Vim, but once in a while I feel like using a full-IDE and I use Eclipse with Pydev at those times.

It depends on your own preference, some people absolutely love Vim and won't use anything else. Others just can't work without an IDE.

Here's a list of:

- Python IDEs: http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments
- Python editors: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors

Answer (score 2):

In terms of using an IDE or not, it doesn't matter. I prefer using an IDE since I like having the tools I need bundled up into one nice, neat little package that can handle all of my development. However, using a text editor is just as good, especially ones as powerful and extensible as vi(m) and (x)emacs. The real reasons for using an IDE, though, are code completion, management of indentation, code folding, refactoring support, and debugging.

If you want to check out other IDEs for Python development, I would suggest also looking at NetBeans and Eclipse with the appropriate plugins. I, personally, prefer NetBeans since I have a feeling that PyDev is going to be going downhill since Aptana bought them (previously, they ruined RadRails, which is the Eclipse plugin for Ruby on Rails development) and don't want to get comfortable with a tool that might not be useful long-term.

Comment: "code completion, management of indentation, code folding, refactoring support, and debugging." Emacs can do all of those, Vim can do most. (I'm not sure about the debugging support in Vim, I just use GDB)

Comment: My understanding is that those are extensions or plugins to Vim and Emacs and not native to the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

With Java, I'd say no IDE for beginners, because you have to understand CLASSPATH first.

With Python, I'd say [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) from JetBrains.  IntelliJ is the best Java IDE; PyCharm is making my Python work a pleasure.

Comment: I heard a lot of nice things about PyCharm and JetBrains,but i am just doing this thing for fun and hopefully learning something ,so i dont think i wanna pay for the tools i use,especially when i am coding in linux :)

Comment: There's a Linux version.  And it'll be $49 for me when it comes out, since I already have an IntelliJ license.  It pays for itself with all the time it saves you.

Comment: At this price, I see it more as charity. Also, I am charitable and a linux user, and see no problem in that.

Comment: Charity?  I'm not following you.  It's just good business - it's not Microsoft Visual Studio.  I think the capabilities and the prices are better for JetBrains products.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, not using IDE to develop is just like using typewriter to write a novel. Nobody said you can't, but why you have to try that hard when you already have laptop?

Comment: Using an IDE is like developing with a typewriter to write a novel. Nobody said you can't, but why try that hard when you already have a laptop with a text editor that lets you type extremely fast and navigate text quickly?

Answer (score 1):

I code in Vim for python. If you want to use an IDE then I would recommend IntelliJ's PyCharm. I use vim because the actual editing is far superior and if you are a power user there is very little that you can't do easily.

PyCharm provides help with api by providing completion and helps with some basic refactoring. These advantages though wear of sooner than you would expect. I use grep and vim regex to do  refactoring - its a bit more work than pycharm but if you can manage it then the advantages of vim clearly outweigh using an ide.

I assume that you are developing in a *nix environment, if you use windows then I would recommend using an Ide.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to some other guys here, I think that an IDE *does* add much to software development, even for a dynamically typed language like Python which makes it harder to do static analysis.

My preferred IDE for Python development is Eclipse with PyDev. Before that, I coded in Notepad++ which isn't much different than the PyDev editor in terms of features. PyDev has some great features that you won't find in a "normal" editor:

- It shows warnings and syntax errors (almost) in realtime. A text editor won't tell me about typos, but PyDev does. As another example, unresolved imports or undefined functions (e.g. because of a typo) are marked as warnings/errors. And there are many more common mistakes that are automatically detected, and PyDev can be integrated with [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) so that warnings and errors from pylint are displayed with the usual icons in the editor.
- Autocompletion by introspection
- Outline view of the current module and its classes

Additionally, Eclipse itself is also great for any kind of programming project. I especially like the fully integrated interface - project explorer, editor, outline, console, problems overview, run configurations and so on. When using Vim, Emacs or similar, I guess you would have to install lots of plugins or custom scripts to achieve the same.

As you said you want to do a project, I think that Eclipse is a good choice. For quickly hacking a small Python script, it's overkill of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you just start learning python/glade/gtk stack, I'd say you should start without an IDE just to learn how it works internally. This will help you later when your code will be bigger and more complex.

However, good IDE helps in so many ways I wouldn't recommend against using any in the long run. This article might help you decide whether you need any: http://infoworld.com/d/developer-world/infoworld-review-nine-fine-python-development-tools-374

Answer (score 0):

it's horses for courses, personally i'm much happier with textmate or vim and a nice cup of coffee but it's what feels more comfortable to you.

there's no shame in using an IDE, if it's what gets your idea out there to the masses the most productive then use whatever you like.

however when starting out i'd favour something with intellisense as it'll teach you the basics as you type, give it a year and you'll be a master at it.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to approach this:

1. Use what you're used to. If you have used an editor in the past and know its quirks, stick with it. You'll waste less time figuring out how to work with the tool and spend more time on the actual project.
2. Use something new. Anjuta, vim, whatever, as long as you haven't spent too much time with it so far. You'll learn a whole lot of stuff besides your actual project, but the project itself won't be done as fast as could be.

Personally, I prefer 2. Always learn something new, as long as it's not crunch time and it-has-to-be-done-by-friday. An IDE can help you only so much, but when you're still in the learning phase the more time you spend on the code yourself, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python programmer, but I prefer not to use IDEs.
The reason for this is that I find IDEs are often big and do too many things for me, whereas using Notepad++ and the command prompt allows me to trim things down to suit my needs rather than being surrounded by features that I don't use. This allows me to learn more easily, because I have more control over what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Don't learn coding with an IDE. Code with it!

Answer (score 0):

I find using an IDE to dramatically help my Python code productivity.  In particular, using wingide makes coding in python a pleasure.  It has all the normal things you would expect (syntax highlighting, auto-complete, etc) but the killer features are the debugger and the debug probe.

These two features are worth the cost of the program.  It lets you see the live state of the application and try out python statements live at breakpoints.  I find this especially helpful to explore the current state and to try out some code to see if it will work.  I often write some of the trickier sections of code in the debug probe live and them copy them into my application.  Very nice.