# Error While Execution in Cmd prompt

Tags: java

i have a java code for send a mail while i am executing the following error is shown

```
.\SendEmail.java:5: package javax.mail.Message does not exist
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
                         ^
.\SendEmail.java:6: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
                          ^
.\SendEmail.java:7: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
                          ^
.\SendEmail.java:8: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

and the another java class for write some values in database, in that the following error will show

```
                           ^
.\WriteHelper.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WorkbookSettings
location: class WriteHelper
                WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WorkbookSettings
location: class WriteHelper
                WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
                                                  ^
.\WriteHelper.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableWorkbook
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSett
ings);
                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Workbook
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSett
ings);
                                            ^
.\WriteHelper.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableSheet
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableFont
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10
);
                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableFont
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10
);
                                             ^
.\WriteHelper.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable WritableFont
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10
);
                                                          ^
.\WriteHelper.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableCellFormat
location: class WriteHelper
                times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
                            ^
.\WriteHelper.java:58: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableFont
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(
                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:58: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableFont
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(
                                                          ^
.\WriteHelper.java:59: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable WritableFont
location: class WriteHelper
                                WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false
,
                                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:59: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable WritableFont
location: class WriteHelper
                                WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false
,
                                                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:60: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable UnderlineStyle
location: class WriteHelper
                                UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
                                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:61: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableCellFormat
location: class WriteHelper
                timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderli
ne);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:65: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CellView
location: class WriteHelper
                CellView cv = new CellView();
                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:65: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CellView
location: class WriteHelper
                CellView cv = new CellView();
                                  ^
.\WriteHelper.java:90: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label=new Label(j,k,JavaSamp.date.get(z),timesBold
Underline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:90: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label=new Label(j,k,JavaSamp.date.get(z),timesBold
Underline);
                                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:92: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label1=new Label(m,k,JavaSamp.motherboard.get(z),t
imesBoldUnderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:92: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label1=new Label(m,k,JavaSamp.motherboard.get(z),t
imesBoldUnderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:94: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label2=new Label(p,k,JavaSamp.processorid.get(z),t
imesBoldUnderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:94: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label2=new Label(p,k,JavaSamp.processorid.get(z),t
imesBoldUnderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:96: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label3=new Label(pn,k,JavaSamp.processorname.get(z
),timesBoldUnderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:96: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label3=new Label(pn,k,JavaSamp.processorname.get(z
),timesBoldUnderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:98: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label4=new Label(bn,k,JavaSamp.biosname.get(z),tim
esBoldUnderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:98: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label4=new Label(bn,k,JavaSamp.biosname.get(z),tim
esBoldUnderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:100: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label5=new Label(bid,k,JavaSamp.biosid.get(z),time
sBoldUnderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:100: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label5=new Label(bid,k,JavaSamp.biosid.get(z),time
sBoldUnderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:102: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label6=new Label(bman,k,JavaSamp.biosname.get(z),t
imesBoldUnderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:102: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label6=new Label(bman,k,JavaSamp.biosname.get(z),t
imesBoldUnderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:104: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label7=new Label(cval,k,JavaSamp.install_countlist
.get(z),timesBoldUnderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:104: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label7=new Label(cval,k,JavaSamp.install_countlist
.get(z),timesBoldUnderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:106: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label8=new Label(8,k,JavaSamp.maxval,timesBoldUnde
rline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:106: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label8=new Label(8,k,JavaSamp.maxval,timesBoldUnde
rline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:108: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label9=new Label(9,k,JavaSamp.maxsysval,timesBoldU
nderline);
                        ^
.\WriteHelper.java:108: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                        Label label9=new Label(9,k,JavaSamp.maxsysval,timesBoldU
nderline);
                                         ^
.\WriteHelper.java:117: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                Label label;
                ^
.\WriteHelper.java:118: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Label
location: class WriteHelper
                label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
```

Why this type of errors are araise if any possibility to overcome it

Comment: How you run them? it seems like your classpath is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are class path errors. The classes you are using should be present in the classpath of the JVM.

Let's take the following example

```
.\WriteHelper.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WritableSheet
location: class WriteHelper
                WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
                ^
```

This message means: In `WriteHelper.java`, line 40, you are referring to a class `WritableSheet` but the compiler is unable to locate where this class is.

The compiler searches for the classes used in your program in the [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29).
Claspath is the path (set of directories or jar files) that the compiler and the runtime look when they encounter a class that they "don't know". (Class they "know" are those that are part of the java language (classes in `java.lang` or `java.math` for example). These are in the classpath by default.

You have to specify all the classes you are using in your class in the classpath.

`WritableSheet` is from the jexcel library (If i am not wrong). So you have to include this library in your class path while compiling the class *and* while running the class.

You do so using the -cp option of `javac` and `java`:

```
javac -cp ./lib/jxl.jar MyClass.java
```

`./lib/jxl.jar` is what I assume as the location of the jExcel library. This cal be anything, just make sure you give the correct path here.

You run the class as

```
java -cp ./lib/jxl.jar MyClass
```

If you are using an IDE ([You should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208193/why-should-i-use-an-ide/208221#208221)), you have add the location of the jxl.jar to the IDE's classpath.

Comment: hi Nivas while i'm execute this cmd the following error also arise

Comment: hi nivas while i using this cmd the below err will arise

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaSamp/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaSamp.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: JavaSamp.class.

Comment: @BEN Ten, This is because the `JavaSamp` class is not in the class path while running. You will have to give this in while running the class using java -cp

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the correct classpath when compiling/running.

Answer (score 1):

add mail api jar (probably mail-1.4.jar) and jExcel jar file (http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) in the class path.

if you are running the java code from command line .. like java [className] then give

java -cp mail-1.4.jar;jexcelapi.jar [className]

otherwise put these jar file paths in environment variable CLASSPATH