# JavaEE Build tools: Eclipse, Maven, Whatever

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven

I have a newbie question...
I started learning java web development with eclipse (because it takes too much time to compile and put classes into corresponding directories). Actually, eclipse possesses every tool to develop anything there.
But a few days ago I realized that in the books I read about javaEE development eclipse is not even touched upon or referenced - everything the author does is using such tools as Maven, JUnit...
So I started wondering - maybe not learning Maven I am missing something out? 
What is it used for (except structuring of the application), what are its benefits over eclipse? Which IDE`s do developers in companies use to create and deploy javaEE applications? If Maven is used, how do they type the program itself - in Notepad?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a real mess in terms. So here are some quick tips:

- **Eclipse** is an IDE, you have that right.
- [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) is many things but not an IDE - it can help you manage dependencies, build process etc.
- [JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junit) is a testing framework.
- All of them can be used together in **Eclipse** and you can write your code as usual. These tools just help you with some repetitive tasks.
- I recommend you not to use Notepad for Java development and suggest you to read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208193/why-should-i-use-an-ide).